# How can I disable Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.TestFailedException

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to disable the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.TestFailedException when I am debugging my unit tests.  The problem is when I open the Exceptions dialog in Visual Studio I can't find this Exception.  Does anyone know how to stop this exception from being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to "Add" the Exception type. In that Exceptions dialog for debugging,

1. Click "Add..."
2. Set Type to CLR Exceptions
3. Enter the full name, including the namespace... so "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.TestFailedException"
4. Click OK

Hope that does it for you!